# How to add custom attribute to Wordpress wp_editor text-area ?

Tags: wordpress, wp-editor

How to add custom attributes to Wordpress **wp_editor** textarea field ?

In Official documentation there is no way to do this. I need to add client side validation attribute (data-bvalidator="required") to text-area which is generated by **wp_editor** method of WordPress.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are not an option for adding custom attributes in `wp_editor()`

So you need to add custom Attribute in `text-area` field using `JQuery`

First add extra class(es) to the editor `text-area`

```
$settings =   array(
    ......
    'editor_class' => 'customclass_for_addattr',
    ......
);
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings  );
```

After wp_editor() function add below jQuery code. it's add the custom attribute to `text-area` using jQuery `atrr` method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery(".customclass_for_addattr").attr('data-bvalidator','required');
   });
</script>
```